VS Code Apex Debug Replayer : "Running Java Command .... failed"
I am trying to run the Apex Replay Debugger and keeps getting the following VS Code Apex Debug Replayer : "Running Java Command .... failed" error. It used to work on my computer (windows) but now I keep getting this issue and there's not a whole lot of info out there on google. Any help is appreciated.
Also Apex language server could not provide information about valid endpoints.



What happens if you copy and paste that command into a command prompt/terminal?

@sfdcfox It runs fine in the command prompt... I'm not able to paste the entire thing but the end of it is..
java version "1.8.0_401"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode)

That's your problem, I think. Try installing Java 17 instead.
